# how to get the wordpress posts into another wordpress site on different server

Tags: php, database, wordpress, rss

I have two sites with different server. I need to get  post of one site to another wordpress site. I have database and cpanel of both server. I guess i can do using rss feed  or fetching the database directly. I need to get all the post content including images and all. so i think rss feed will not be the better solution.

Please suggest me the better solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use [WP API](http://v2.wp-api.org/)

e.g.

```
$posts = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=20&filter[orderby]=date'));
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    echo '<a href="'.$post->link.'">'.$post->title->rendered.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks silver, it is very much useful for me.

Comment: WP api needs wordpress version 4.4 and above.

Comment: https://topod.ir/blog/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_fields=id,thumbnail,excerpt,title,link&per_page=1

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the approach you want to use as this question is primarily opinion-based.

Although,

One and good approach is to have a single database for both the server. As mentioned in your question, images and other media will get shared too.

So On the second server you can connect to the main database of the first server and then whenever you show the media like images, show it from the first server (By using URL of first server). For this you might need to update the codes of the second server.

Comment: single database for both sites ? nope, it won't work `wp-options` table has keys called `siteurl` and `home`. even you access another site this will be redirected to original site.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is master and slave concept.
Make a plugin for your WordPress site and listen to new posts by filters. whenever a new post comes in , write it to another WordPress site's database.

Reference:
`wp_insert_post()` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Comment: Thank you. I think it is also good option.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform this using wordpress inbuilt functionality that is import and export through wordpress admin.

Just go to your wordpress admin from where you want to shift all post.Then go to tools section and click on export and select posts in your case. You can also export all content, pages etc. using this. You will get a .xml file, just download it.
Check here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Tools_Export_Screen

Now, go to wordpress admin of your another website where you want to import content. Just go to tools and click on import and go with the flow.

Comment: yes i am aware of this features of wp. But i need to appear the post from one site to the another site automatically . Thank you for answer WpTricks

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress have a builtin export function. Export that from the other site and import on the other site.